# Vue2 page when to query url in lifecyle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a page where I want to display a message if a user comes from a certain URL:

If arriving from this URL:

http://www.testapp.com?_a=lookingforthis&token=5b6b7f/account/about

```
<template>Show this message</template>
```

If from here:
http://www.testapp.com/account/about

```
<template>Dont show this message</template>
```

Would I need to do this in mounted() or method()?

Id this the correct way to trigger this?

```
this.$route.query?.lookingforthis
```

Comment: `computed()` sounds nice for that purpose. Or inline conditional into the template.

Comment: @kissu thanks you. Can I ask if this.$route.query?.lookingforthis is valid in this example?

Comment: `http://www.testapp.com?_a=lookingforthis&token=5b6b7f/account/about` is not really valid. Especially since the query is `_a` here and that the path is after the query, it should be the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work well

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ showOrNotTheMessage }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    showOrNotTheMessage() {
      return this.$route.query?.lookingforthis
        ? 'Show this message'
        : 'Dont show this message'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Being triggered on an URL like `http://localhost:3000/about?lookingforthis=TEST`.

As shown if using the Vue devtools

[image]

PS: if `TEST` is missing, it's `falsy` as expected.

Comment: What if I only want to check "lookingforthis" is in the URL, regardless of value

Comment: @Pianoc if there is no value, it's supposed to be empty. You could double check that one with `Object.keys(this.$route.query).includes('lookingforthis')` but I do not recommend that because I'm pretty sure the "HTTP spec" is all about having a value (like `TEST`) or not having a query at all. Having a query with no value seems just wrong and could probably be fixed with either a fallback or by using another approach.

Comment: Got it, thank you for explaining this well. Appreciated.

Comment: @Pianoc does it solve your issue? Got more questions regarding router queries?

Comment: It helps a lot, I was possibly approaching this incorrectly. I would still like to know the correct way to query if a url contains something e.g how would I query if the current URL in this example contained "ook"

Comment: @Pianoc my initial snippet is in the case where you have `lookingforthis=TEST`. This is how you should be using a query param, with a `key/value` pair. Otherwise, you can not follow the conventions insured by the people taking care of the browser spec and only use a conditional on the `key`, where you could inspect that one with `Object.keys(this.$route.query).includes(key)`. There is no other use case so far that I can think of. Feel free to explicit some other approach or the actual issue you're trying to solve with your query param. Maybe query param is not what you need at all in your case